# Query dates from different rows in the same table to appear on the same row in the query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have seen many posts about this issue using joins but not for the same table.  I am trying to compare the dates from different rows on the same table.  I am writing tax software that tracks liens.  The tax charge is on one line and any interest charged is on another.  I need to compare the dates of the tax line and the dates of the interest line here is the query I tried

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    TAX_YEAR, 
    (SELECT TAX5_DATE FROM Tran_File WHERE TRAN_CODE = '878LOT' AND TAX5_DATE IS NOT NULL) AS TaxLineLienDate,
    (SELECT TAX5_DATE FROM Tran_File WHERE TRAN_CODE = '878LOI' AND TAX5_DATE IS NOT NULL) AS InterestLineLienDate
FROM
    Tran_File

WHERE 
    TAX5_DATE IS NOT NULL
    AND (TRAN_CODE = '878LOT' OR TRAN_CODE = '878LOI')
```

The sub query is returning multiple records.  I want the TaxLineLienDate and InterestLineLienDate on the same line of the query for each ID.  Any help would be appreciated.  I am using SQL Server.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Sample data (with DDL) and expected results help us help you.

Comment: I think it is terrible that you vote down some ones question.  Yes I could improve the question but this discourages people form asking questions.  It is a legitimate question and questions should not be voted down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you can use `conditional aggregation` for this:

```
select id, 
    tax_year, 
    max(case when TRAN_CODE = '878LOT' then TAX5_DATE end) TaxLineLienDate,
    max(case when TRAN_CODE = '878LOI' then TAX5_DATE end) InterestLineLienDate
from Tran_File
where TAX5_DATE is not null
    and TRAN_CODE in ('878LOT', '878LOI')
group by id, tax_year
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  This solved my issue.  The only thing is it returns null values for the TAX5_DATE if one TRAN_CODE has a value but the other does not.  Can I specify no null in the Case Statement?

Answer (score -1):

`CASE WHEN` could be one of the option.

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    TAX_YEAR, 
    CASE WHEN TRAN_CODE = '878LOT' AND TAX5_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN TAX5_DATE ELSE NULL END AS TaxLineLienDate,
    CASE WHEN TRAN_CODE = '878LOI' AND TAX5_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN TAX5_DATE ELSE NULL END AS InterestLineLienDate
FROM
    Tran_File

WHERE 
    TAX5_DATE IS NOT NULL
    AND (TRAN_CODE = '878LOT' OR TRAN_CODE = '878LOI')
```